# How to use second level cache for lazy loaded collections in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, lazy-loading, second-level-cache

Let's say I have two entities, `Employee` and `Skill`.  Every employee has a set of skills.  Now when I load the skills lazily through the `Employee` instances the cache is not used for skills in different instances of `Employee`.

Let's Consider the following data set.

```
Employee - 1 : Java, PHP
Employee - 2 : Java, PHP
```

When I load Employee - 2 after Employee - 1, I do not want hibernate to hit the database to get the skills and instead use the `Skill` instances already available in cache.  Is this possible?  If so how?

**Hibernate Configuration**

```
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pass</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/cache</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>

    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

    <mapping class="org.cache.models.Employee" />
    <mapping class="org.cache.models.Skill" />
</session-factory>
```

**The Entities with imports, getters and setters Removed**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    public Employee() {
    }

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "employee_skills", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "skill_id"))
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    private List<Skill> skills;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "skill")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Skill {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;
}
```

**SQL for Loading the Second Employee and his Skills**

```
Hibernate: select employee0_.id as id0_0_, employee0_.name as name0_0_ from employee employee0_ where employee0_.id=?
Hibernate: select skills0_.employee_id as employee1_1_, skills0_.skill_id as skill2_1_, skill1_.id as id1_0_, skill1_.name as name1_0_ from employee_skills skills0_ left outer join skill skill1_ on skills0_.skill_id=skill1_.id where skills0_.employee_id=?
```

In that I specifically want to avoid the second query as the first one is unavoidable anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You need to cache the `Employee--<>Skills` association. Example taken from [Speed Up Your Hibernate Applications with Second-Level Caching](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/29685/1954) below:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.wakaleo.articles.caching.businessobjects">
    <class name="Employee" table="EMPLOYEE" dynamic-update="true">
        <meta attribute="implement-equals">true</meta>    

      <id name="id" type="long" unsaved-value="null" >
            <column name="emp_id" not-null="true"/>
            <generator class="increment"/>
      </id>

    <property column="emp_surname" name="surname" type="string"/>
    <property column="emp_firstname" name="firstname" type="string"/>

    <many-to-one name="country"
            column="cn_id"
                class="com.wakaleo.articles.caching.businessobjects.Country"  
            not-null="true" />

    <!-- Lazy-loading is deactivated to demonstrate caching behavior -->    
    <set name="languages" table="EMPLOYEE_SPEAKS_LANGUAGE" lazy="false">
        <cache usage="read-write"/>
        <key column="emp_id"/>
            <many-to-many column="lan_id" class="Language"/>
    </set>                              
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Note the `<cache>` element inside the  of languages.

Comment: I've done this already.  It avoids the query only for those employees which are already loaded.  Not employees not in cache who also have the same skills as another employee already in cache.

In my initial example it would work if I load Employee - 1 again but not when I load Employee - 2.

Comment: @Chandru Can you please show your mappings **and** the generated SQL?